# The difference between indeterminate and undefined operation.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I want to know the difference between these two terms. My prof told me they are different.

Comment: Have you learned about limits? I think indeterminate talks about limits.

Comment: Yes, He told me that $\infty - \infty $ is both undefined and indeterminate, but he said that $\infty+\infty$ is simply undefined but it is not indeterminate. Your answer will improve my understanding of the concept. I just need a more formal one.

Comment: An operation can't be indeterminate. We may say it is undefined (as in "division by zero is undefined") if we are lazy.

Comment: I know what you mean here that is why I want a more formal definition.

Answer (score 3):

These statements are about limits.  When your prof says that $\infty + \infty$ is undefined, what he means is this: If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \infty$, then $\lim_{x\to a} (f(x) + g(x))$ does not exist (that is, is undefined).  In this case, we can be a little more precise and say $\lim_{x\to a} (f(x) + g(x))=\infty$.  The very fast and loose way to write this statement is: $\infty + \infty = \infty$.  But again, this is a statement about limits, not about arithmetic with $\infty$, which is after all not a number.

Suppose now that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = \infty$.
What can you say about $\lim_{x\to a} (f(x) - g(x))$?  You might guess the limit must be zero.  It turns out the answer is **nothing**.  Consider each of the cases (let $a=\infty$):

- If $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x$, then the limit is $\infty$.
- If $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$, then the limit is $-\infty$.
- If $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x^2$, then the limit is $0$.
- If $f(x) = x+1$ and $g(x) = x$, then the limit is $1$.  You can see how this case can be modified to make the limit any real number.
- If $f(x) = x + \sin x$ and $g(x) = x$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x))$ does not exist, nor is it even infinite.

So although we have a shorthand statement “$\infty + \infty = \infty$”, there's no analogous shorthand statement for “$\infty - \infty = \Box$.”  This is what it means for a limit to be in indeterminate form—there's no limit theorem that allows us to evaluate it in its current form.

But as you can see in the examples above, *indeterminate* is not the same thing as *undefined*.  A limit in indeterminate form could be finite, infinite, or neither.  It also doesn't mean the limit is unknown or unknowable.  It just means we have to work a bit before we can find if the limit exists and what it might be.

Comment: Certainly you are in agreement with Chidzalo's definition, you just need to make it a little more elegant.

Comment: @PewaniJoza: We are certainly saying the same things.  But I would stop short of *defining* indeterminate.  A definition starts with "A foo is called bar if and only if..." What would "foo" be if "bar" is indeterminate?  Not "limit", because *a limit is not an object; it is a statement*.  To make a precise definition requires a level of precision that obscures the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I thik that an example can be useful.

Consider a function $F(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. If there is some $x_i$such that $g(x_i)=0$ the the function $F(x)$ is **undefined** for such $x_i$ because we can not divide by $0$.

If we consider the limit:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_i}F(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_i}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$
than this expression is **defined**, i.e. it has a well defined meaning, but it is different from $F(x_i)$ that does not exists, and can be *determined* or *undetermined*, depending on the behavior of the two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ at $x_i$. If $f(x_i) \ne 0$ then the limit is defined and **determined** (it is $\infty$) but if $f(x_i)=0$ than we say that it is **undetermined**, but note that that does not means that we cannot calculate its value.